# Exercise on strongly quasi-invariant types

Tags: logic, model-theory

I specify some definitions that are necessary to understand the exercise I'm working on:

Given a monster model $\mathfrak{U}$ (of inaccessible cardinality) and a set $A\subseteq \mathfrak{U}$, we say that a set $B \subseteq \mathfrak{U}^{|x|}$ (where usually $x$ is a tuple of free variables, maybe infinite) is quasi-invariant over $A$ if, whenever $f_1,\dots,f_n$ is a finite tuple of automorphisms over $\mathfrak{U}$ that pointwise fix $A$, we have that the sets $f_i[B]$ have non-empty intersection.
We say that a type $p(x)\subseteq L(\mathfrak{U})$ is quasi-invariant over $A$ if $\varphi(\mathfrak{U})$ (as a set) is quasi-invariant over $A$ for every conjunction $\varphi(x)$ of formulas in $p(x)$. (Note that here $x$ may be an infinite tuple of free variables)

We say that a set $B$ is strongly quasi-invariant over $A$ if for every definable set $D\subseteq \mathfrak{U}$ we have that at least one of $B\cap D$ and $B \cap \neg D$ is quasi -invariant. The extension of such definition to types is done in the same way as for quasi-invariant types.

Here is the exercise:

> Prove that every strongly quasi-invariant type has an extension to a complete strongly quasi-invariant type. Hint: it may help to prove that if $B$ is strongly quasi-invariant then for every definable $D$ either $B\cap D$ or $B \cap \neg D$ is strongly quasi-invariant

I have tried in many ways but I have problems in proving even the claim in the hint. Any help?

---

EDIT: I managed to prove the result but by strengthening a bit the definition of strongly quasi-invariant sets. The new definition I gave is the following:

We say that a set $B$ is strongly quasi-invariant over $A$ if for every finite equivalence relation $\varepsilon(x;y) \in L(\mathfrak{U})$ there exists a $c \in \mathfrak{U}^{|y|}$ s.t. $B \cap \epsilon(\mathfrak{U};c)$ is quasi-invariant. In other words if for every finite and definable partition of $\mathfrak{U}^{|x|}$, there exists a partition element $D$ s.t. $B\cap D$ is quasi-invariant.
Using this new definition, the claim in the hint follows pretty easily.

I've thought about it and I think that this new definition is strictly stronger than the previous one (i.e. the new strongly quasi-invariant sets are a proper subset of the old strongly quasi-invariant sets ), but I'm not sure about it.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, what is the source of this exercise? The notion of quasi-invariant is quite nice, but new to me (I think), and I'm curious whether it appears in the literature.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for the answer. Does your hint refer to the exercise's hint or to the main claim? The exercise is taken from my professor's notes, but at the beginning of this chapter he specifies that these notions are non-standard.

Comment: @AlexKruckman https://github.com/domenicozambella/creche/blob/master/creche.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I spoke too soon in my first comment (now deleted). Given the hint in the exercise, the rest follows formally, but I don't see why the hint should be true.

Comment: @AlexKruckman In the end I managed to prove it by strengthening a bit the definition of a strongly quasi-invariant set. I'll write it in an edit

Comment: Yes, this adjustment to the definition of quasi-invariant is exactly what you need to prove the theorem. An equivalent and more common way to phrase the condition is this: $B$ is strongly quasi-invariant over $A$ if and only if whenever $B\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i$, where each $D_i$ is definable, at least one of the $D_i$ is quasi-invariant over $A$.  When I first read your question, I assumed that the definition of "strongly quasi-invariant" would be equivalent to this, but now I think you're right that the new condition is strictly stronger (but I don't have a counterexample in mind).